# Store the count of stored procedures into a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having 5 stored procedures and i am trying to store the count of each stored procedure into a table .

These are the stored procedures

```
select * from sp_table1();
select * from sp_table2();
select * from sp_table3();
select * from sp_table4();
select * from sp_table5();
```

Is it possible to write a stored procedure that stores the count of each procedure

Comment: Isn't that just `insert mycounts(name,num) select  'table1',count(*) from sp_table1()`

Comment: So, those stored procedures return some rows and you want to store the count of rows for each of these in another table?

Comment: What does "the count of each stored procedure" mean?

Comment: @KaushikNayak Yes